# My PC is not POSTing unless I force it off

Tags: boot, bios

I recently bought a second hand PC but it won't power on everytime. If it successfully powers on, it will single beep and show bios logo and windows and what not. Now, when I press on button, fans and GPU light turns on but there is no display and no beep. GPU light also turns red. Then I hold power button to force it off. Then I turn it on again and it single beeps and gives warning that it is in safe mode from forced shutdown or failed POST. From here it lets me go to BIOS and then I can manually boot windows from there. I had this issue before, and I updated bios image and that fixed it. Now issue is back and bios is latest version. The motherboard is a Asus H110M-R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was tinkering around and after resetting default settings in the BIOS the problem is fixed. There was no hardware failure or PSU failure.